# Windows 10 Programs not reponding or opening after a couple hours

Tags: windows-10

So I reluctantly upgraded to Windows 10 from 7 a couple days ago. Upgraded graphics driver immediately after. Restart, all seemed fine. Played a game with PCSX2 for a couple hours, check out youtube, no problem.

Next day the pc has restarted at some point, thanks windows 10, and I went to play but the game wouldn't launch. PCSX2 launched fine but once I tried booting the iso it didn't launch and pcsx wasn't responding. Forced closed, reopened, same thing. Restart the pc and everything works... for a couple hours until pcsx wouldn't boot the iso again.

Today, same issue but this time I tried a few other things. PCSX2 launched but the iso didn't, force close. Then tried Project64. It launched but the rom didn't. Force close. Steam was already running so I tried to launch a game. Didn't launch. Steam said it was running but I didn't see it in the task manager. Exited Steam. Attempted to reopen through the start menu and nothing. Clicked on it and it didn't open. Attempted to open Blizzards laucher and nothing. No response. Opened Firefox and it seemed to work fine. Restart the pc and everything works again. Launch a game in Steam, no problem. Game in pcsx, no problem.

I have googled everything I could regarding this but most searches bring up issues regarding the specific software and not really anyone with quite the same issue of a restart fixing things for a couple hours. I'm pretty casual with pcs but if I was to guess it is something kicking on after a few hours that causes this.

Any ideas of what might cause this would be appreciated.

Basic specs
Asus z87 pro mobo, i7 4770k cpu, gtx 1070, 16g ram, main drive is 250g ssd, multiple other hdd

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there was some memory exhaustion. You say "Next day the pc has restarted at some point, thanks windows 10" without any qualification. It is *possible* that some rogue or failing process allocated a ton of memory causing Windows' "out of memory killer" (OOM) to kill other processes making it *look* like a reboot.

That no other program *looks* like it is able to run is indicative of a system that is trying to push stuff out to the page file, again, memory starvation. Windows 10 greys out the window for the application when it is not responding, but "not responding" covers a multitude of sins, up to and including the application trying to allocate memory on a system that is heavily using the page file and trying to contend with the delays that can occur.

Unless you know your system is 100% perfect the grayed out "not responding" is not necessarily "not working". Many old programs go into deep code while working and don't update their GUI, Windows is just overzealous in showing you that the app is "sleeping", even old versions of Windows did this, though they didn't show it as obviously.

Rebooting would have killed the program or application that stole all the memory and started from a clean slate. If everything is now fine then chances are it *was* simply out of memory.

The offending program could have been your network card driver, one of your emulators that didn't close properly or a poorly written webpage in Chrome. Blaming Windows, despite it's history of system breaking updates, is premature and unfounded.

Comment: So if it's a program that is eating up memory, would I see my memory usage spiked through the task manager monitor?

Comment: In theory yes, but some system processes may cause hardware drivers to start allocating memory and not be easy to find via task manager. Think video players in web browsers using graphics card video decoders and so on. I've heard people mention a Microsoft program called RAMMap for more detailed memory use statistics.

Comment: Interesting. I will look into that program and see if that can catch anything. Would an issue like this be logged in an event viewer? Also, I just assumed it was a win 10 issue because it didn't do this 3 days ago with 7.

Comment: Can't find anything on the event log except https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8b135cc8-2128-4639-b856-58434c699051/log-event-in-event-viewer-for-high-memory-utilization?forum=winserver8gen. It is possible that in upgrading from 7 to 10 a driver didn't get cleanly upgraded and has a problem, I've seen it with graphics drivers at least. It might be worth doing an update on those at least. Also check things like antivirus and so on.